# How to redirect to previous page in Ruby On Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

I have a page that lists all of the projects that has sortable headers and pagination.

```
path:
/projects?order=asc&page=3&sort=code
```

I choose to edit one of the projects

```
path:
projects/436/edit
```

When I click save on that page, it calls the projects controller / update method.  After I update the code I want to redirect to the path that I was on before I clicked edit a specific project. In other words, I want to be on the same page with the same sorting.

I saw link_to(:back) and thought that :back may work in redirect_to(:back), but that's a no go.

```
puts YAML::dump(:back) 
yields the following:
:back
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 342, accepted):

In your edit action, store the requesting url in the session hash, which is available across multiple requests:

```
session[:return_to] ||= request.referer
```

Then redirect to it in your update action, after a successful save:

```
redirect_to session.delete(:return_to)
```

Comment: doesn't having several tabs open confuse this logic?

Comment: Couldn't you just `redirect_to request.referer`?

Comment: @DanMundy No, for it to work it should be `request.referer.referer`, if that could be possible. @Jaime Bellmyer Why `||=`?

Comment: @jones yes. There is also confusion if you switch to another model edit.
I'm also interested in why ||=

Comment: Doesn't make any sense to use `||=` since you *do* want to overwrite the variable, otherwise you won't have the latest page visited.

Comment: It works for me in Rails 7.  I put it in my `application_controller` in the authorize method.

Answer (score 106):

Why does `redirect_to(:back)` not work for you, why is it a no go?

`redirect_to(:back)` works like a charm for me. It's just a short cut for 
`redirect_to(request.env['HTTP_REFERER'])`

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/redirect_to (pre Rails 3) or http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Redirecting/redirect_to (Rails 3)

Please note that `redirect_to(:back)` is being deprecated in Rails 5. You can use

`redirect_back(fallback_location: 'something')` instead (see http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/29/rails-5-improves-redirect_to_back-with-redirect-back.html)

Comment: `redirect_to :back` does not work well for me either, say you visit `/posts/new`, this is set as the referer for the next request, so after the form is successfully submitted it shows the form again, i.e `/posts/new`. It does however work well for other purposes.

Comment: That is, OP wants to redirect back twice. I bet he could just `redirect_to projects_path`.

Comment: Yeah. redirect_back does not work as well in Rails 5

Comment: @strizzwald what does "does not work well" mean? Any details?

Comment: @pascalbetz, What I meant is that if `HTTP_REFERER` is not set, you may  get `ActionController::RedirectBackError`, you would have to rescue from this exception in that case. From my understanding, using `redirect_back` does not require any exception handling since you are forced to provide `fallback_location`. Maybe 'does not work well' is not the right way to put it.

Answer (score 46):

I like Jaime's method with one exception, it worked better for me to re-store the referer every time:

```
def edit
    session[:return_to] = request.referer
...
```

The reason is that if you edit multiple objects, you will always be redirected back to the first URL you stored in the session with Jaime's method.  For example, let's say I have objects Apple and Orange. I edit Apple and `session[:return_to]` gets set to the referer of that action. When I go to edit Oranges using the same code, `session[:return_to]` will not get set because it is already defined.  So when I update the Orange, I will get sent to the referer of the previous Apple#edit action.

Comment: yes, but can you suggest what to do if accidentally same url was stored as you are at? You are at apple and you came from apple. And you want previous location

Answer (score 35):

This is how we do it in our application

```
def store_location
  session[:return_to] = request.fullpath if request.get? and controller_name != "user_sessions" and controller_name != "sessions"
end

def redirect_back_or_default(default)
  redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
end
```

This way you only store last GET request in `:return_to` session param, so all forms, even when multiple time POSTed would work with `:return_to`.

Comment: yup that's pretty good. I would only suggest to generally not use`and` and `or` in `if` statements. Use `&&` and `||` instead. Details [here](http://devblog.avdi.org/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/).

Answer (score 25):

In rails 5, as per the instructions in Rails Guides, you can use:

```
redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
```

The 'back' location is pulled from the HTTP_REFERER header which is not guaranteed to be set by the browser. Thats why you should provide a 'fallback_location'.

Comment: This feature appears in rails 5.

Comment: @pSkarl How can I pass a `notice` object with the `redirect_back` statement in order to tell the user something went wrong with a flash message?

Comment: Well, I could solve this by doing: **`redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path, notice: "Something went wrong!")`**. Hope [it could](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_back) help somehow.

Answer (score 18):

`request.referer` is set by Rack and is set as follows:

```
def referer
  @env['HTTP_REFERER'] || '/'
end
```

Just do a `redirect_to request.referer` and it will always redirect to the true referring page, or the root_path ('/').  This is essential when passing tests that fail in cases of direct-nav to a particular page in which the controller throws a redirect_to :back

Comment: Not sure which file you were looking at but at the rack source, this is how `referer` was defined as of [28 Mar 2011](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/828e2ab0396c5bbf4b5ccd76e6392a475633a81f/lib/rack/request.rb#L222-L224), and that is how it is defined as of [today](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/bbae0ce30ddeb9f8a2a208d08e479ee5a85a1a02/lib/rack/request.rb#L289-L291). That is, `|| '/'` is not part of the definition.

Answer (score 2):

```
link_to 'get me back', :back
```

The symbol `:back` is your swiss army knife.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are interested, here is my implementation extending MBO's original answer (written against rails 4.2.4, ruby 2.1.5).

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  after_filter :set_return_to_location

  REDIRECT_CONTROLLER_BLACKLIST = %w(
    sessions
    user_sessions
    ...
    etc.
  )

  ...

  def set_return_to_location
    return unless request.get?
    return unless request.format.html?
    return unless %w(show index edit).include?(params[:action])
    return if REDIRECT_CONTROLLER_BLACKLIST.include?(controller_name)
    session[:return_to] = request.fullpath
  end

  def redirect_back_or_default(default_path = root_path)
    redirect_to(
      session[:return_to].present? && session[:return_to] != request.fullpath ?
        session[:return_to] : default_path
    )
  end
end
```

Comment: Will these not return you to a different path when you are editing 2 or more items?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this will work

```html
  def edit
    if request.referer != request.original_url
        @return_here =  request.referer
    end

  end
```

and use @return_here as a hidden value in the submit form.

of course reloading will kill this so just go back to a default fall back as needed.