# Redirect to original destination after logging in

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 2.3.11

If a user tries to go to /photos when they aren't logged in, they are directed to `[site]/admin/login?route=[site]/photos`.  After they log in, I would like them to be sent to whatever was defined in "route" instead of the default home page.

**In /app/controllers/admin_controller.rb:**

```
def login
    if session[:user_id] #already logged in
      redirect_to ''
    @destination = request.url
    end
    if request.post?
      if [authentication code]
        if user.activated? #check to see whether the user has activated their account
          session[:user_id] = user.id
          if params[:route] # ********
            redirect_to "#{params[:route]}"
          else
            redirect_to :controller => 'home'
          end
        else
          flash.now[:notice] = "Your account hasn't been activated yet.  Check your emails!"
        end
      else
        flash.now[:notice] = "Invalid email/password combination"
      end
    end
  end
```

The "*****"ed line is the one that isn't working correctly.  When I check to see the parameters, :route isn't among them, so the argument isn't being passed in with the login post.  Can anyone explain to me why it isn't and how I could fix it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
session[:return_to] ||= request.referer
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139996/ruby-on-rails-redirect-toback

Comment: This looks like it should do the trick, but I'm still pretty new at Rails, so could you kindly elaborate a little on where I should put that?  Would it go in my application controller (where it redirects visitors who aren't logged in to the log-in page) or somewhere in the method posted above?  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you; that worked (once I figured it out)!

For all others, what I ended up having to do was this:

Have a before_filter that directs to an authorization method:
`def authorize
    unless logged_in?
      session[:original_target] = request.request_uri
      flash[:notice] = "You must be logged in to view that page"
      redirect_to home_url
    end
  end`

Then, in my login controller, after authenticating the user, check to see whether there's anything stored in session[:original_target] and, if there is, go to that.