# Forward the user back to a post after adding a comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forwarding

This is probably a fairly simple thing to do - I have a site with a news feed that shows various posts. There are also other pages that similarly show posts. Comments can be added to these posts directly from any of these pages.

What I need to do is redirect the user back to the URL they came from, once they've added a comment, and to the particular post they commented on (each post has an id of `post-#{post.id}`, so I'd just have to stick `#post-2` or whatever to the URL.

If the post could not be saved, for whatever reason, I'd also like to have the content that the user had submitted pre-filled into the comment box after the redirect.

How can I do these two things? The first is the more important one..
I'd have to store the URL that the user is coming from in the session on the new action and redirect to this on the create action? How can I get the URL?

I'm on Rails 3.1 by the way.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [redirect :back](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-redirect_to) which will send the user back to the page that issued the request

```
redirect_to :back
```

Comment: Thank you. I found exactly what I want [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139996/ruby-on-rails-redirect-toback), but that's quite close to it :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Comment is a resource nested under Post in your routing (/posts/123/comment/new):

```
def create
  comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
  if comment.save
    redirect_to post_path(comment.post)
  else
    redirect_to new_post_comment_path(params)
    # or maybe you have the comment form on the Post#show page
    # redirect_to post_path(params)
  end
end
```

Comment: I do not want to redirect to the post path. I want, instead, to redirect back to the page the user commented from. Which could be any other page, say the news feed.