# How do I redirect back to a page I'm currently on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

In my users photo album page they see photos they have uploaded and each photo has a 'make default' link on it.
When the user clicks `make default`, then the id of the photo is stored in the `photo_id` column of my profiles table.

The issue is redirecting them back to:

```
localhost:3000/settings/photo_gallery/:id
```

Is there a way I can redirect back to the photo album using the id of the photo that has just been set as the default? Can Rails find what album I want to redirect to just by looking at the id of a photo, as a photo belongs to a photo album, and a photo album has many photos?

I have the following tables in my database:

- User(s): has one profile, has many PhotoAlbums
- Profile(s): belongs to user
- PhotoAlbum(s): belongs to user, has many photos
- Photo(s): belongs to PhotoAlbum

Controller action:

```
def set_default_profile_photo

  photo = Profile.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)
  photo.photo_id = params[:photo_id]
  photo.save

  redirect_to "**HERE IS WHERE I'D LIKE TO REDIRECT TO THE PHOTOALBUM THE PHOTO IS IN**"
  flash[:success] = "Default photo set!"

end
```

My routes:

```
                    users GET    /users(.:format)                                  {:action=>"index", :controller=>"users"}
                          POST   /users(.:format)                                  {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}
                 new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                              {:action=>"new", :controller=>"users"}
                edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                         {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}
                     user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                              {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
                          PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                              {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users"}
                          DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                              {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users"}
                 sessions GET    /sessions(.:format)                               {:action=>"index", :controller=>"sessions"}
                          POST   /sessions(.:format)                               {:action=>"create", :controller=>"sessions"}
              new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)                           {:action=>"new", :controller=>"sessions"}
             edit_session GET    /sessions/:id/edit(.:format)                      {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"sessions"}
                  session GET    /sessions/:id(.:format)                           {:action=>"show", :controller=>"sessions"}
                          PUT    /sessions/:id(.:format)                           {:action=>"update", :controller=>"sessions"}
                          DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)                           {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"sessions"}
                passwords GET    /passwords(.:format)                              {:action=>"index", :controller=>"passwords"}
                          POST   /passwords(.:format)                              {:action=>"create", :controller=>"passwords"}
             new_password GET    /passwords/new(.:format)                          {:action=>"new", :controller=>"passwords"}
            edit_password GET    /passwords/:id/edit(.:format)                     {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"passwords"}
                 password GET    /passwords/:id(.:format)                          {:action=>"show", :controller=>"passwords"}
                          PUT    /passwords/:id(.:format)                          {:action=>"update", :controller=>"passwords"}
                          DELETE /passwords/:id(.:format)                          {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"passwords"}
                 profiles GET    /profiles(.:format)                               {:action=>"index", :controller=>"profiles"}
                          POST   /profiles(.:format)                               {:action=>"create", :controller=>"profiles"}
              new_profile GET    /profiles/new(.:format)                           {:action=>"new", :controller=>"profiles"}
             edit_profile GET    /profiles/:id/edit(.:format)                      {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"profiles"}
                  profile GET    /profiles/:id(.:format)                           {:action=>"show", :controller=>"profiles"}
                          PUT    /profiles/:id(.:format)                           {:action=>"update", :controller=>"profiles"}
                          DELETE /profiles/:id(.:format)                           {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"profiles"}
                   emails GET    /emails(.:format)                                 {:action=>"index", :controller=>"emails"}
                          POST   /emails(.:format)                                 {:action=>"create", :controller=>"emails"}
                new_email GET    /emails/new(.:format)                             {:action=>"new", :controller=>"emails"}
               edit_email GET    /emails/:id/edit(.:format)                        {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"emails"}
                    email GET    /emails/:id(.:format)                             {:action=>"show", :controller=>"emails"}
                          PUT    /emails/:id(.:format)                             {:action=>"update", :controller=>"emails"}
                          DELETE /emails/:id(.:format)                             {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"emails"}
                     root        /                                                 {:controller=>"users", :action=>"new"}
                  success        /success(.:format)                                {:action=>"success", :controller=>"users"}
                    login        /login(.:format)                                  {:action=>"new", :controller=>"sessions"}
                   logout        /logout(.:format)                                 {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"sessions"}
           reset_password        /reset_password(.:format)                         {:action=>"new", :controller=>"passwords"}
       setup_new_password        /setup_new_password(.:format)                     {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"passwords"}
                 settings        /settings(.:format)                               {:action=>"settings", :controller=>"users"}
         settings_account        /settings/account(.:format)                       {:controller=>"users", :action=>"account"}
    settings_edit_profile        /settings/edit_profile(.:format)                  {:controller=>"profiles", :action=>"edit_profile"}
                                 /:username(.:format)                              {:controller=>"users", :action=>"show"}
          change_password        /change_password(.:format)                        {:action=>"change_password", :controller=>"users"}
profile_photo_set_default        /profile_photo/set_default(.:format)              {:controller=>"photo_albums", :action=>"set_default_profile_photo"}
  album_photo_set_default        /album_photo/set_default(.:format)                {:controller=>"photo_albums", :action=>"set_default_album_photo"}
             photo_albums GET    /settings/photo_gallery(.:format)                 {:action=>"index", :controller=>"photo_albums"}
                          POST   /settings/photo_gallery(.:format)                 {:action=>"create", :controller=>"photo_albums"}
          new_photo_album GET    /settings/photo_gallery/new(.:format)             {:action=>"new", :controller=>"photo_albums"}
         edit_photo_album GET    /settings/photo_gallery/:id/edit(.:format)        {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"photo_albums"}
              photo_album GET    /settings/photo_gallery/:id(.:format)             {:action=>"show", :controller=>"photo_albums"}
                          PUT    /settings/photo_gallery/:id(.:format)             {:action=>"update", :controller=>"photo_albums"}
                          DELETE /settings/photo_gallery/:id(.:format)             {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"photo_albums"}
                   photos GET    /settings/photo_gallery/photos(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"photos"}
                          POST   /settings/photo_gallery/photos(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"photos"}
                new_photo GET    /settings/photo_gallery/photos/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"photos"}
               edit_photo GET    /settings/photo_gallery/photos/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"photos"}
                    photo GET    /settings/photo_gallery/photos/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"photos"}
                          PUT    /settings/photo_gallery/photos/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"photos"}
                          DELETE /settings/photo_gallery/photos/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"photos"}
```

Comment: This link may be useful for you. Hope it will help. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139996/ruby-on-rails-redirect-toback

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`redirect_to :back` worked for me but I want to see if this was the right choice
http://api.rubyonrails.org/files/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/redirecting_rb.html

Comment: Looks like the right thing to me. If you didn't have the option of using redirect_to :back, you could get the same result with redirect_to PhotoAlbum.where(:id => Photo.where(:id => params[:photo_id]).first.photo_album_id). There are better ways of doing this query but this should work.

Answer (score 35):

This is what you want:

```
redirect_to request.referrer
```

For further reference:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer

Answer (score 28):

In Rails 5 it was introduced the function:

```
redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
```

It does redirect back whenever the `HTTP_REFERER` is known. Otherwise it redirects to the `fallback_location`.

The `redirect_to :back` is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 5.1.

Comment: How can I pass a `notice` object with the `redirect_back` statement in order to tell the user something went wrong with a flash message?

Comment: Well, I could solve this by doing: **`redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path, notice: "Something went wrong!")`**. Hope [it could](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_back) help somehow.

Answer (score 1):

In one project we used the session for temporary storage, because `redirect_to :back` did not work for us.
We had an `def new` where we set `session[:return_to] = request.referer`
in the `def create` we added `redirect_to session[:return_to]`.
I do not know anymore, why we could not use `redirect_to :back`

Comment: The reason that you did not use `redirect_to :back` is most likely because you are wanting to go back **two** steps, i.e. if you went 'back' from `create` you would be taken back to `new` which is why you actually want to go back two steps to whatever was before `new`.

Answer (score 0):

If you came from the photo_album page, you should be able to do:

```
redirect_to :back
```

Otherwise, you should be able to do a named route like:

```
redirect_to photo_album_path(photo.album_id) # or whatever the association key is
```

BTW, why do you have photo_albums mapping to photo_galleries? It's a lot less confusing if you named your resources and routes in a similiar manner. ie: if you wanted your route endpoints to use /photo_galleries you should name your resource PhotoGallery.