# Rails 4 & Devise 4: Keep user on current page after updating profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have a User model, and I am hoping to have different pages to edit their info so that I don't have everything on `edit.html.erb`

So far I have created views for `page_content.html.erb` and `donation_options.html.erb` which have my forms on them. Both work as intended and successfully update my User, but after submitting the form I am redirected the User root, which is `show.html.erb`. I would like to set it up so that the user stays on the current page after updating their profile. I am not sure if I need to edit my `UsersController`, or create a new controller, or take a different approach.

Here's an example of my form:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
              <!--Some inputs-->

              <div class="actions">
                <%= f.submit 'Update', :class => "btn btn-primary"  %>
                <!--After submitting, I'm taken to /users/:id/. I'd like to stay on /users/:id/current_view-->
              </div>
          <% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have a `UsersController` you should set something up comparable to this:

```
Class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update(user_params)
      redirect_to your_path_here
    end
  end
end
```

I am not sure exactly what your `UsersController` looks like, but that should give you an idea. After a user is updated, use `redirect_to` with your path you would like the User sent to. You may also use `redirect_to :back` if you are looking to redirect back to the current page you are on.

Please see this existing [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952487/how-do-i-redirect-back-to-a-page-im-currently-on).

Comment: Fantastic, this was 100% the answer. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help :)