# Rails - Email controller redirect confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, referer

I have a controller that deals with contact emails. I have an action like this:

```
def representative
    @contact = UserContact.new()
    if request.method == 'POST'
     @contact = UserContact.new(params[:merchant_contact])
     if @contact.valid?
      @contact.contact_email = current_user.email
      @contact.contact_phone = current_user.phone_number
      Emailer.representative_contact(@contact, representative).deliver # sends the email
          redirect_to **????**, :flash => { :notice => "Thank you! Someone will get back to you shortly."}
     else
      render :representative
     end
    else
     render :representative
    end
end
```

I call **contact_representative_path** from different places in my code, and I want that, after submission a redirection to where the user clicked the **contact_representative_path**. I have tried with :back, but it just renders the representative view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

redirect_to and return does not end the requests, in order to end the request you need to add return at the end.

Try with `redirect_to contact_representative_path,:flash => { :notice => "Thank you! Someone will get back to you shortly."} and return`

UPDATE

In session hash, you can store the  requesting url which will be available across multiple requests.
 `session[:return_to] ||= request.referer`
Then call `redirect_to session[:return_to], :flash => { :notice => "Thank you! Someone will get back to you shortly."}`

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139996/ruby-on-rails-redirect-toback), hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: that doesn't answer my question. I want to return from where I come from. What you suggest will always redirect to contact_representative_path.

Comment: I think I had missed the last part of your question, Edited my answer.