# How to return to previous page after Devise sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

After a successful login via Devise, how can I redirect the user back to the page they were on?

I've read and searched a lot already, and I understand that I need to define `after_sign_in_path_for`. I've done this and its working correctly, what I'm having trouble with is understanding how the previous page is stored, and how to call it correctly.

I have this in my sessions controller:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    return request.env['omniauth.origin'] || session[:user_return_to] || root_path
end
```

I've also tried

```
...
return request.env['omniauth.origin'] || stored_location_for(resource) || root_path
...
```

I don't think I am understanding how to store the location, as the user is redirected back to the root path if they click to log in.

A sign in can be initiated in two ways. Either (a) the user attempts to access a restricted view (i.e. `before_filter :authenticate_user!...`, in which case they are redirected and prompted to login. Or (b) the user clicks a sign in link which is available on every page if the user is not logged in.

(a) seems to be working. (b) is not. I guess I need to store the current location to session when the user clicks the log in link.

How do I do this? Or, where is a good source of information that would help me understand this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get the previous url using `request.referrer` as is explained in this SO question: [How to redirect to previous page in Ruby On Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139996/ruby-on-rails-redirect-toback)

Comment: thanks. So would you set this to the session under new in the sessions controller?

Comment: never mind. I replaced `stored_location_for(resource)` with `request.referrer` in the `after_sign_in_path_for` method. This works perfectly without needing to store the value in the session.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly, and a really useful reference. I've given the answer to cage as he beat you by a minute, and has a lower score. But thanks, have an up mark

Comment: @AndyHarvey Actually, it seems that I beat him as far as time is concerned (by a little under 2mins).  It shows that I posted the answer at `2012-05-17 06:51:25Z`, whereas Cage posted it at `2012-05-17 06-53-09Z`.  Just wondering if you're seeing the same timestamps?

Comment: By the time I need this, I am POSTing to `/users/sign_in`, and my `referrer` is also `/users/sign_in`, since we just did a GET there to see the login page itself. I need to get the path *before* the sign on page.

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
redirect_to request.referrer
```

Answer (score 2):

Heads up: The code should go in your application_controller.rb, not sessions controller.

How it works is that newer versions of Devise automatically store the initial page the user tried to visit (before getting redirected to sign in).

That can be accessed by using the devise helper: `stored_location_for(resource)`

What you add to your application controller is something like this:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  stored_location_for(resource) || users_dashboard_path
  # replace users_dashboard_path by whichever route you want to redirect to after login - default is root_path
end
```

After a successful sign in, Devise will automatically run your method from application controller instead of it's own (overriding it).

For a more complex example, here's one from the Devise team:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  stored_location_for(resource) ||
    if resource.is_a?(User) && resource.can_publish?
      publisher_url
    else
      super
    end
end
```

I hope this answer helps anyone searching how to do this with newer versions of devise.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach. I am enabling this "return to" feature only on certain links (via the `continue` URL parameter). In the example below I am taint checking `params[:continue]` prior to assigning it to `session[:continue]` in the `after_action` - *though perhaps that is unnecessary if you have authorization in place*. Finally, in the `after_sign_in_path_for` method override I [delete](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-i-delete) `session[:continue]` meanwhile using it (as it is not needed afterwards) - deleting the key/value pair returns the value if the key matches, otherwise `nil` is returned, in which case the statement falls back on `root_path`.

**app/views/journal/show.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to 'sign in', new_user_session_path(continue: journal_url(@journal)) %> or
<%= link_to 'sign up', new_user_registration_path(continue: journal_url(@journal)) %>
```

**app/controllers/application_controller.rb**

```
after_action :store_location

def store_location
    if params[:continue] =~ /\/(journal\/[0-9]+|foo|bar)\z/ # safelist
        session[:continue] = params[:continue]
    end
end

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    session.delete(:continue) || root_path
end
```