# Do I need to validate session variables in every controller action? (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, redirect, controller

Sort of a follow-on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139996/ruby-on-rails-redirect-toback).

In my application, I have a Task model. Multiple pages can link to a single Task's "edit" url. For example, `/tasks/1/edit` is linked to from `/tasks/1` and `user/1/` (User being another model).

In my controller, I want to be able to redirect back to any one of the referring pages after the "edit" is submitted via an "update" action. For example, if I go to `/tasks/1/edit` from `user/1/`, after the "update" action I want to redirect back to `user/1/`. Same deal if I go to `/tasks/1/edit` from `/tasks/1`.

In my GET "edit" action I am doing:

```
@task = Task.find(params[:id])

if request.referer and (request.referer == task_url(@task) or request.referer == user_url(@task.user))
  session[:return_to] = request.referer
else
  session.delete(:return_to)
end
```

In the corresponding PUT "update" action I do:

```
@task = Task.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  if @task.update_attributes(params[:task])
    format.html { redirect_to session.has_key?(:return_to) ? session[:return_to] : @task #return to task if no return_to specified
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

This works, but I am concerned that the client could spoof/fake their `session[:return_to]` in the "update", allowing them to redirect to whatever page they want.

Does that matter? Is this a valid concern? Do I need to validate `session[:return_to]` in the "update"?

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes...

request.referrer stores the URL that brought a user to your site. If you did the following:

1. Create a static HTML page
2. Embed a link to the /task/1/edit
3. At the end of the update, it would redirect back to the static web page.

To solve this problem, what you should do is store a session variable that denotes the location (e.g. in your UsersController, do a before_filter and set session[:return_task_update_to] = :users)

And then, at the end of the update, you redirect back, and clear the :return_task_update_to variable in the session. You would obviously also handle the case if there is no session variable (in which case you would redirect to whatever made sense as a default).

This way, you don't need to validate the URL or do something crazy. Simply set up the state in the session, and redirect if it exists.

Comment: Could you provide an example? I'm not quite sure what you mean and where I'm supposed to do the filter.