# Devise: after_sign_in_path_for(resource) not working

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using devise for user sign up/in. But when user signs in from public accessible pages, devise redirects to root_path.

I tried to use this:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
 request.referrer
end
```

When user tries to sign in, it gives error 'not redirected properly'.

Can anybody tell how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe if I am right what you want to do is override the redirect when a user sign in is to change the following method inside `controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb` If you haven't generated devises controllers you [generate devise controller](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Tool%3a-Generate-and-customize-controllers). Having done that you will want to have something like the following inside your `devise/sessions_controller.rb`

```
 def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
   # respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if current_user.role? :administrator
      redirect_to dashboard_path
    else
      redirect_to rota_days_path 
    end
  end
```

In the above example by default the `sessions_controller - create`  method uses the following:  `# respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)` which I have commented out. By adding a if statement that checks if the current_users role is an administrator. If they then they are redirected to the dashboard page. If not then they are redirected to the rota page.

Alternatively the devise helpers state that you could also do something like:

```
      def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
       stored_location_for(resource) ||
         if resource.is_a?(User) && resource.can_publish?
           publisher_url
         else
           super
         end
     end
```

Hope this helps.

**Update**

```
 def create
    @hospital_booking = HospitalBooking.new(params[:hospital_booking])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @hospital_booking.save
        format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'Photographer Shift was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @hospital_booking, status: :created, location: @hospital_booking }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @hospital_booking.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

What happens here is when the `hospital_booking` is saved it redirects back to the issue page instead of redirecting to another page. Further reading here: [api dock- redirect_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/redirect_to)

Comment: what is publisher_url? if it replace it with 'request.referrer', it gives error 'The page isn't redirecting properly'. How to redirect user to back page?

Comment: @user2206724 where are you doing this `def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)` is this inside `controllers/devise/session_controller.rb`. Furthermore `publisher_url` is just an example of what the `devise_helper.rb` show.

Comment: I am defining it application controller, it is working if i replace request.referrer with any other defined path. But i dont want defined path, i want it to redirect to back/previous page.

Comment: @user2206724 Okay I believe what you want is to `redirect_to` back to the page that issused the request. In usual cases you can use `redirect_to :back` I will show you an example

Comment: @user2206724 see update and have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139996/ruby-on-rails-redirect-toback