# Redirect to current page rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes

I have a sign in form in my application nav bar and I was wondering if there is an easy way to have to sign_in redirect to whatever page you are currently on when you sign_in.  Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

You can `redirect_to(:back)`, as long as a referrer is given. However, I'd recommend that you take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139996/ruby-on-rails-redirect-toback), as the solution presented there will be resilient to things like failed logins and OAuth redirects.

Answer (score 7):

In Rails 5, you should use `redirect_back` and add fallback path:

```
redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
```

Answer (score 4):

In **Rails 7+** we can now use [redirect_back_or_to](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_back_or_to)

```rb
redirect_back_or_to root_path
```

**Note:** `root_path` can be any fallback path / url you want.

Comment: The function is actually `redirect_back_or_to`, but yes this is the way to go!

Comment: @JillianHoenig whoops, updated the answer to use the correct order.

Answer (score 2):

If you have written the code to create a session for your user ,then simply add this line after that in your sessions_controller:

```
redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged in!"
```

here instead of **root_url** you can enter any path you wish the user be redirected to.
but make sure you have it in you **routes.rb**
and if you considering the unsuccessful sign_in you can use `render` method to reload your sign_in view

Comment: The problem is that I want the `redirect_to` path to change baised on where the un logged in user is currently on the site.  The nav bar is visible on every page so for example, if the user is on the Home page when they sign in, i want the sessons_controller to run `reidrect_to home_path` or if they are on the user page when they log in I want it to run `redirect_to user_page`

Comment: and do you have your sign_in form in another view or in the bar you mentioned?

Comment: It is located in the nav bar, so it is in the applications layout

Comment: I haven't tried but as you know you can render a `.json` file in your controller.so you need to write a javascript function to reload the page and render that file in your controller.something like `location.reload() `

Answer (score 1):

[`redirect_back`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44098668/5783745) is what worked for me:

```rb
redirect_back fallback_location: root_path
```

Answer (score 0):

[This solution](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update) from the Devise folks should do the trick...

In `ApplicationController` write the following:

```
after_filter :store_location

def store_location
  # store last url - this is needed for post-login redirect to whatever the user last visited.
  return unless request.get? 
  if (request.path != "/users/sign_in" &&
      request.path != "/users/sign_up" &&
      request.path != "/users/password/new" &&
      request.path != "/users/password/edit" &&
      request.path != "/users/confirmation" &&
      request.path != "/users/sign_out" &&
      !request.xhr?) # don't store ajax calls
    session[:previous_url] = request.fullpath 
  end
end

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  session[:previous_url] || root_path
end
```