# rails redirect_to :back not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect

I'm trying to use the following:

```
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController

  def addproduct
     (session[:products] ||= []) << params[:item]
     redirect_to :back
  end

 end
```

I got this exception:

```
undefined method `back_url' for #<PaymentsController:0x007ff682c467a8>
```

Why this is happening?

Comment: Do you get `ActionController::RedirectBackError` in the console?

Comment: In the console I get the exception I wrote up.

Comment: @Lechucico : Which version of Rails are you using? From Rails 5, it is `redirect_back` with a fallback option.

Comment: rails 5.1.1 version

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Rails 5 has [`redirect_back`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_back), instead of `redirect_to :back`. It was changed as it used to raise an exception when request's `HTTP_REFERER` was not present.

So use this:

```
redirect_back fallback_location: root_path
```

You can change `root_path` to something else as per your requirements.

Comment: But this will redirect me to root_path?

Comment: @Lechucico : That's the point. It will redirect to root_path, only when there's no way to redirect back to the path from which request originated.

Answer (score 16):

`redirect_to :back` was deprecated in Rails 5.0 (see [PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/22506)) and then removed in Rails 5.1

Use the following instead:

```
redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
```