# Previous page after updating rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, hyperlink

I am trying to go back to the previous page after updating a link. Here is my link controller:

```
def update

  if @link.update(link_params)
    redirect_to :back
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @link.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

Although the link does update, it the page only refreshes, instead of going back to the previous page. Could someone help point out what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You'll want to store the referrer in a session. Look at this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139996/ruby-on-rails-redirect-toback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Referrer**

Each time you load a controller action in your application, you'll get a [`request` object](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html), which *should* have the [`referer` attribute](http://apidock.com/rails/Rack/Request/referer):

```
def update

  if @link.update(link_params)
    redirect_to request.referer 
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @link.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are sending a request from your browser in a way that it wants to handle the response as if you were going to a new page. `redirect_to :back` simply tells rails to send the referrer as the redirect URL. If the code read `redirect_to 'http://google.com'` you would expect the browser to go to google.com, would you not? The correct thing to is to make an asynchronous call using javascript and use javascript to go back in the event of success.

How this happens depends on which JavaScript library you are using. Simply make the call, and in your success function, call `window.history.back()` and the browser will go back.