# How to redirect_to(:back) two times?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
def update
  if @note.update_attributes(note_params)
    redirect_to :back, notice: "Note was updated."
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

Is there a way to redirect back twice?

Comment: How do you know where they came from two clicks ago?

Comment: Anything useful in [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139996/ruby-on-rails-redirect-toback)?

Comment: They came from one of four show pages @Makoto because notes are polymorphic so when they click to edit their note then click update they are redirected back to the note edit form, but I want them to redirected back to the show page if possible :)

Comment: No @Kimball they don't address going back twice but thanks for trying

Comment: If you have the route for the show page, just redirect them to the show page.  One can't empirically say that they know where a user came from two clicks ago, but if you have an exact target, use that.

Comment: It's one of 4 show pages so I don't know which one.

Comment: Instead of redirect_to :back two times, use `super`

Comment: How would that look as an answer @test I need to start giving you some points for your help :)

Comment: Use binding.pry and before redirecting to back and check what `super` keyword gives you

Comment: Can't you save the referring page in session state? Even if you end up duplicating the code in 4 (or more!) places it seems less likely to haunt you than going back twice. What if the user has multiple tabs open in the same session? No way of knowing where "back twice" is, as @Makoto implies.

Comment: You can save the referring page address into the hidden field in the form, submit the form so the hidden field will pass the page address to the Update method, then use that to redirect back to the show page. How does it sound?

Comment: @MrH that sounds like it might work. Can you show me in an answer with how I would implement that. Do you need any more code from me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:
This is where the link for editing goes:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<% url = "#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}#{request.fullpath}" %>
<%= link_to 'Create New Page and Return Here', edit_page_path(1, :url => Base64.encode64(url) ) %>
<br>
```

After submit your url will be something like this: 
 http://localhost:3000/pages/1/edit?url=aHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDozMDAwL2R1bW1pZXM%3D%0A

In the edit form:
I called it pages/_form.html.erb, Pass the URL as a hidden params.

```
<%= form_for(@page) do |f| %>
  <% if @page.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@page.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this page from being saved:</h2>    
      <ul>
      <% @page.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>    
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :permalink %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :permalink %>
  </div>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :url, params[:url].to_s %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

In controller that you have update method, in this case pages_controller.rb, simply `Base64` it back and redirect the user:

```
 def update
    redirection = nil
    if params[:url].present?
      redirection = Base64.decode64(params[:url].to_s)
    end
    if @page.update(page_params)

      if redirection.present?
        path = redirection
      else
        path = @page
      end
      redirect_to path, notice:  'All Done.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

Now user updates the form and redirected back to the first show or index page or any page that she is coming from.

Hope this help.
PS: You might want to clean it up a bit and pass the url from the controller, and put some checks on it. So you don't define any var at the view level. In the above code I just tried to solve this issue not really a design pattern oriented :)