# Rails redirect to index page after delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to place delete link at the show page of the object. This show page is to rendered at two different controllers. In which I need to redirect to the index page from which the request came from. The URL would be
localhost:3000/users (index page) which will have link to books (show page) that URL will be local host:3000/books/I'd. And at another controller index page local host:3000/books and that too have link to books show page which have delete link in it. I need to redirect to the index page from which the request came from. Any help

Edit:
How to redirect to previous page in Ruby On Rails? (Question already there)
We can get the request URL at edit action. But here the delete action will be at common show page

Comment: Please post some codes, so that we can do some help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect to previous page in Ruby On Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139996/how-to-redirect-to-previous-page-in-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 3):

You could track the visit to the index pages by storing it in the session:

```
class ApplicationController
  private 
  def store_location
    session[:stored_location] = request.path
  end

  def stored_location
    session[:stored_location]
  end
end

class UsersController
  before_acton :store_location, only: [:index]
  # ...
end

class BooksController
  before_acton :store_location, only: [:index]
  # ...
end
```

You can this just use it your destroy action:

```
class BooksController
  def destroy
    @book.destroy
    redirect_to stored_location || books_path
  end
end
```

Comment: The request URL would have book id. Because the delete request would trigger on show page. If I redirect to the request path it won't exist as that was already deleted. If I wrong please correct me

Comment: This is going to redirect the end-user to the previous page, which is the show page of the just deleted record :(

Comment: @MrYoshiji Yeah I guess I should have added a condition that checks if the request is from the show action action. Edited.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. There are two different index action both of them have common show page link. There is a delete option at show page. Need to redirect to the index page from which the show action call was triggered

Comment: Same basic approach but just save the location on the index actions you want to "track".

Comment: But I edited the answer to better fit your exact use case. A slightly more complex but more reusable solution would be to store the locations as an array like the browser history API. But you can leave that until you actually want / need that feature.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you can put the following in your `delete` controller:

```
redirect_to :back
```

that should redirect back to the page the user came from.

Comment: `redirect_to :back` is depreciated in Rails 5.1 because it raises an error if the Referer header is not present.

Comment: I would not go with redirect_to : back, as the request would trigger on show page

Comment: @Aarthi I guess I misunderstood the question, I was under the impression the 'Delete' links were on the index pages.

Answer (score 0):

#### ruby 2.5.1p57 | Rails 5.2.0

Put at the end of your method:

```rb
redirect_to action: :index
```